# SIM800L module for arduino will not call or send message sometimes

Tags: c, arduino, gsm

The code works but  many times it fail to call/send message even when  interface is right connected. It fails about 10% and the program is moving on. How to retry to call if there is any error  on calling(maybe on signal or whatever)?I think I  have to deal with [AT](http://cristiansteib.github.io/Sim800l/info/SIM800+Series_AT+Command+Manual_V1.09.pdf) commands but I don't know how to handle that. I am using this [library](https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/GPRS_SIM900). AT commands are [here](http://cristiansteib.github.io/Sim800l/info/SIM800+Series_AT+Command+Manual_V1.09.pdf) . My full code is [here](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/6387).

```
#include <GPRS_Shield_Arduino.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>


#define PIN_TX    7
#define PIN_RX    8
#define BAUDRATE  9600
#define PHONE_NUMBER "003xxxxxxxxxx"
#define MESSAGE  "Temp is high"

GPRS gprsTest(PIN_TX, PIN_RX, BAUDRATE); //RX,TX,BaudRate

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // code 

}

void loop() {

// ..code..


  if (temp>35) {
    call_and_text();
  }

// ..code..

}

call_and_text() {
  while (!gprsTest.init()) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("init error1\r\n");
  }
  Serial.println("gprs init success");
  Serial.println("start to send message ...");
  gprsTest.sendSMS(PHONE_NUMBER, MESSAGE); //define phone number and text
  Serial.println("Init success, start to call...");
  gprsTest.callUp("003xxxxxxxxx");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the return of `sendSMS` and `callUp` functions to determine whether they succeeded or not.

And for your problem, are you powering your GSM shield correctly?
By correctly I mean not from your computer through the USB.

If this is the case, try to use an external power supply with sufficient power. The power supply should be able to deliver up to 2A.

---

Edit to your last comment.

At the moment of calling or sending a message, your GSM shield needs a burst of power. Your 0.7mA may not be sufficient.

If you have another power supply that can deliver more, try it. Note that your arduino can be powered from `6-20V`, although the recommended voltage is `7-12V`.

However, the ideal way is to power your shield and your arduino separately, and have a commun ground. In that way you can always power the arduino from the USB and the shield from it's a proper supply.

Comment: For now I power it from arduino. Arduino is connected with 9 volt power supply 0.7mA. Should I buy another external supply for arduino? Can flow 2A through arduino? If not I have to use  DC-DC 9V to 5V..

Comment: Please see my edit, the comment was going to be long.

Comment: There is another question. When call it return 1 (Call success) but after this GSM may restart (bsc of power issue) so call will fail. How can I check if GSM is ON while it is calling?

Comment: While it's calling you can't. The shield should be busy calling. But right after it you can check if the modem is still on by sending `AT` and waiting for an `OK`.

Comment: So when it is busy commands doesn't work? Even to check just the power or signal?

Comment: Well, it's busy doing work. The only way the check the power and the GSM communication is through the EN and NET LEDs. See your datasheet or the wiki (http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/LoNet_-_GSM/GPRS_Breakout) on how the NET LED should be blinking when everything is good.

Comment: I understand the led but I want to understand the microcontroller too

Comment: Maybe the only way is to use the recommended power supply but sometimes I want to use it just with the portable USB charger.. Then will be many fails on calling

Comment: Well, you can't play a game with your phone while making a call. It's the same thing here, you can't interact with your GSM shield until it finishes what it's doing. For each command you send, you need to wait for the response (OK, ERROR, CONNECT,....) in between any command you send will be discarded.

Comment: And I just saw that, your `call_and_text` function doesn't have any `return`. Your compiler should have warned you about it. Add `void` to it, if you're not planning on returning anything.

Comment: True. So there is not any way to recognise when modem is calling from restarting with commands?

Comment: Maybe can I check if call is ringing after 2 second?

Comment: You can probably use the reports that the shield prints before powering down. In normal power down it prints "NORMAL POWER DOWN", on an under-voltage it prints "UNDER-VOLTAGE WARNING". Please take a look at the Hardware design documents (power-down section) of your shield for more details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116310/discussion-between-dimitris-and-ouss4).

Comment: How can i read the reports before powering down I dont find it on manual?

Comment: Hardware Desing page 24 paragraph 4.2.2 Power Down SIM800L. See all sections Power down by PWKEY, By AT,.... You can send the report to your serial monitor if you wan't to see what's happening.